# Esper create window based on filter

Tags: esper, epl

I am trying to construct a window of object from type TickVo.
I managed to do so using:

```
TickVO.win:time_batch(1 min)
```

but my first tick starts for example from 44 miliseconds after midnight, meaning 00:00:00.44.

my question is:
    how can i make the window start from 0 miliseconds and end in such.
for example: 00:00:00.44 will be added to the window of 00:00:01
but 00:00:01.15 tick will be added to the window of 00:00:02.

because what happens now is that both 00:00:00.44 and 00:00:01.15 are added to the first tick, since ( as i saw) it is relevant to the starting point.

update: after further investigation, i found out that my solution should rely on

```
win:ext_timed
```

but i still haven't figured out the filter i should use as timestamp_expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time-batch can take a reference point as a [parameter](http://esper.espertech.com/release-8.0.0/reference-esper/html_single/index.html#view-win-time-batch) in the form "`TickVO#time_batch(1 min, 0L)`". The zero tells the runtime to align to 0 millis.

There are a few related approaches on the [solution patterns page](http://www.espertech.com/esper/solution-patterns/#aggregate-3).
You may find detailed description of how [batch windows behave](http://esper.espertech.com/release-8.0.0/reference-esper/html_single/index.html#view-batchwindows) useful.
Session windows are generally done using overlapping or non-overlapping [contexts](http://esper.espertech.com/release-8.0.0/reference-esper/html_single/index.html#context).

Comment: Thank you very much!
TickVO.win:time_batch(1 sec,0L) solved it :)